# Binary tree add missing child

Tags: c

The function method and missing held accepts to arguments nodes and X. Node node representing a pointer to the root note of a binary tree and an integer value x the function method and missing child must find the notes which are having only one child in the given binary tree then the function must add the missing child is the value X for those nodes you are task is to implement the function and missing cell so that the program runs successfully use only c

Example input output
Input:
9
10
10 20 L
10 30 R
20 40 L
30 50 L
30 60 R
50 80 R
60 80 R
100
Output
10 20 40 100 50 70 80 60 100 90

Comment: Please consider sharing what you tried and what your difficulty is, as of now this question seems a lot like "pls do my homework"

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```c
void addMissingChild(Node* node, int x)
{
    // Check if the current node has only one child
    if (node->left != NULL && node->right == NULL)
    {
        // Add the missing child with value x
        node->right = new Node(x);
    }
    else if (node->left == NULL && node->right != NULL)
    {
        // Add the missing child with value x
        node->left = new Node(x);
    }

    // Recursively call the function on the left and right children
    if (node->left != NULL)
    {
        addMissingChild(node->left, x);
    }
    if (node->right != NULL)
    {
        addMissingChild(node->right, x);
    }
}
```